# Updating Django template settings from 1.7 to 1.8

Tags: python, django, django-1.7, django-1.8

So I've been tinkering with upgrading to the new version of Django (**1.8**).  I'm currently on version **1.7** and I am struggling to get my production server to listen to the new settings in **1.8**.

As of **1.8**, any `TEMPLATE_*` settings have been deprecated according to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/upgrading/#the-templates-settings) and has been replaced with the `TEMPLATES` setting.

I'm trying to just continue as I was, but I wish to move to the new settings before the deprecation timeline ends.

In my **1.7** settings I have only got two of the old settings which are now deprecated as follows:

```
from django.conf.global_settings import TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS += ("django.core.context_processors.request",)

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
)
```

In the new 1.8 settings I've got the following:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                # Insert your TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS here or use this
                # list if you haven't customized them:
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                'django.template.context_processors.static',
                'django.template.context_processors.tz',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

However when I use these settings, my production server cannot locate the template files, yet my local works just fine.

**EDIT**: Turns out `APP_DIRS` setting being missing was playing havoc with openshift.  I have all my templates in one directory, not in application dirs, but this seemed to resolve the issue.

Comment: your server django version is right? and server template directory is right?

Comment: Server is running django 1.8 the exact same version as my local. The directory is the same also as it's a repository that I upload to directly.

Comment: Do you have a full traceback? It might list the templates template that it failed to find, and the directories that it searched. Secondly, you haven't set `APP_DIRS: True` in your settings. That might cause problems if you use any app that comes with templates (e.g. the admin).

Comment: Check, that os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates') point to the same directory, where you template is located.

Comment: Than submit that as the answer and mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that openshift doesn't read the DIRS: setting unless `APP_DIRS:` is set as `True`

Doing this, fixed the issue.